# MapView very slow when dragging

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here's my app's architecture.

**MainActivity** is just a skeleton that loads MainFragment into its container.

**MainFragment** contains a button, and when clicked, adds MapsFragment.

**MapsFragment** loads mapview. It will also show a custom sized dialog fragment on top of it with `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` set to make that dialog fragment non-modal.

[image]

MapsFragment mapview will work fine if it is launched from within onResume.
Whereas it will be extremely slow when dragging if it is either

1. Launched from Button's onClick, or
2. Launched from onResume with at least 1ms delay.

Here's my video recording
https://youtu.be/x7hFa4Ny4hM

Before 11s, everything worked fine, as it is launched from onResume.
After 12s, mapview becomes very laggy because it is launched from onClick.

If MapsFragment doesn't launch dialog fragment, then mapview will work fine.

It seems like if there's a delay for at least 1ms, then map will lag.
Please kindly help as i've been stuck on this for 3 days.
thanks!

Here's my code

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, MainFragment.newInstance())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

//-------------------------

```
class MainFragment : DialogFragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        // if passing 0, 0, map will work fine, if passing at least 1 ms, map will be slow
        object : CountDownTimer(0, 0) {

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                var left = millisUntilFinished / 1000
                button2.setText("$left")
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, MapsFragment.newInstance())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
            }

        }.start()
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        button2.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, MapsFragment.newInstance())
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
    }
}
```

//-------------------------

```
class MapsFragment : DialogFragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MapsFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
 AddCitiesFragment.newInstance().show(activity!!.supportFragmentManager)
    }
}
```